# using custom HTML in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, css, html

So in the past couple of weeks i have been making moves as to learning how to work with Salesforce.
Now I have been able to use the Apex to insert Data and some other things even to Create The database tables and insert Data. Thats fine and good.
Now I want to create a custom page in Visual Force.

I have some issues here, How do i go about these :

- Installing Visual force
- using my own custom HTML / CSS to Develop Applications that save to the Database so it can be accessed from the Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Qaszi and welcome.

A couple of things to help you get started.

1. If you are interested in development I recommend you start to learn to use a real tool like Visual Studio Code or IntelliJ/Illuminated Cloud. The dev console is not a tool for real development work.
2. You don't need to install Visual Force. If you are using an IDE like VSC you can just create a new VF page. And you can do the same from the dev console. Both Apex and Visual Force are cloud-based and there is no local version you need to install like Python or Node etc..
3. You would be better served by learning to create Lightning Web Components than Visual Force. And it will give you a broader skillset as well.